# choose selected for select option with condition

Tags: menus, conditional-content, select

I have a select option like this

```
            <select name="select1">
                <option value="value1">hots</option>
                <option value="value2">popular</option>
                <option value="value3" >new</option>
                <option value="value4">old</option>
            </select>
```

when a user select one option in the next loading the selected option again is the first one (**value1**),
i managed to find an official solution, i used a **switch case**, like this:

```
$panir=$_POST['select1'];
    switch ($panir) {
        case 'value1':
            ?>
            <select name="select1">
                <option value="value1" selected>hot</option>
                <option value="value2">popular</option>
                <option value="value3" >new</option>
                <option value="value4">old</option>
            </select>
            <?php
            break;
        case 'value2':
            ?>
            <select name="select1">
                <option value="value1">hot</option>
                <option value="value2" selected>popular</option>
                <option value="value3">new</option>
                <option value="value4">old</option>
            </select>
            <?php
            break;}
```

it works great, but has a big problem, i have another **select option** with lots of options and i can't add case as number as them,
isn't there any solution that options would be **selected** by a condition?
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have only 1 select. Before the ">" of each option you can add

`<?php echo ( $_POST['select1'] == 'value' ? 'selected' : '' ); ?>`